# how to make a method for this code

Tags: c++, methods

I have simple question: I dont know how to make a method for codes like this:

```
//how should i put these two lines in a method?
if (agent.GetWorldState().GetPlayMode() == PM_Before_Kick_Off)
{
    agent.Move(Vector(-1, -1));
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: A method is just another name for a member function.  How did you make GetWorldState() and GetPlayMode() and Move()?  It's the same thing.

Comment: You highlite those lines and press ctrl+x then you put a cursor inside of chosen method and press ctrl+v.

Comment: im working on a opensource project(simulation) in c++ and im medifying some parts that my friends wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're asking how to write a method to wrap that code.  If so I think you want the following (assuming the type of `agent` is `Agent`)

```
void TheMethod(Agent& agent) {
  if (agent.GetWorldState().GetPlayMode() == PM_Before_Kick_Off) {
    agent.Move(Vector(-1, -1));
  }
}
```

Comment: yes i just want to wrap that code with this methos,should i define TheMethod in .h file too?thanks

Comment: @arash you should put the method signature in the .h file if it's used in multiple .cpp files.